# Permutation generator with OR operator

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, algorithm, c++17

Problem: Given a vector of strings, I want to print out all possible permutations where the strings may contain an OR operator (the `|` character, as in regular expressions).

Example Input: the strings `race` and `car|horse`

Example Output:

```
race car
race horse
car race
horse race
```

This code uses `-std=c++17` and helper code from other programmers (if this makes it off topic, I will recode these parts).

This is faster than the [Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55318930/10976976) from one of my questions on a sibling site.

Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Begin helper function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/10976976
template <typename Out>
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(iss, item, delim)) {
        *result++ = item;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}
// End helper function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/10976976


// Begin helper function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050528/10976976
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> cart_product (const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& v) {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> s = {{}};
    for (const auto& u : v) {
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> r;
        for (const auto& x : s) {
            for (const auto y : u) {
                r.push_back(x);
                r.back().push_back(y);
            }
        }
        s = std::move(r);
    }
    return s;
}
// End helper function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050528/10976976


int main() {
    std::vector vector_of_strings{"C++|Python|PHP", "Is|Is Not", "Good|Great|Excellent|Exceptional"};
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vector_of_vector_of_strings;

    for (auto& word_possibilities_string : vector_of_strings) {
        auto word_possibilities = split(word_possibilities_string, '|');
        vector_of_vector_of_strings.push_back(word_possibilities);
    }

    // vector_of_vector_of_strings is now {{C++, Python, PHP}, {Is, Is Not}, {Good, Great, Excellent, Exceptional}}

    auto sentences = cart_product(vector_of_vector_of_strings);

    for (auto& sentence : sentences) {
        std::sort(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());

        do {
            const auto seperator = " ";
            const auto* sep = "";

            for (const auto& word : sentence) {
                std::cout << sep << word;
                sep = seperator;
            }

            std::cout << "\n";
        } while(std::next_permutation(sentence.begin(), sentence.end()));
    }
}
```

Output (I'm sure you'll agree with the statements below):

```
C++ Good Is
C++ Is Good
Good C++ Is
Good Is C++
Is C++ Good
Is Good C++
...
Exceptional Is Not PHP
Exceptional PHP Is Not
Is Not Exceptional PHP
Is Not PHP Exceptional
PHP Exceptional Is Not
PHP Is Not Exceptional
```

In the future, I will be reading in `vector_of_strings` from a file and passing in the starting permutation as arguments.

For example: `./permutation_generator words.txt PHP Exceptional "Is Not"` will output:

```
PHP Exceptional Is Not
PHP Is Not Exceptional
```

Answer (score 2):

user673679 already mentioned that a lot of string copying is going on. Indeed, `std::string_view` could be used here to just keep references to the original input strings, saving both time and space.

## Give your variables meaningful names

Your variable names should tell you something about the *contents* of the variable, not of the *type* of the variable. So don't write `std::vector<std::string> vector_of_strings`, but give it a more descriptive name such as `input` if it's the input to your program, and `possibilities` instead of `vector_of_vector_of_strings`.

Also avoid variable names that are too alike, such as `separator` and `sep` in your `main()` function. In this case, you can avoid it by writing the code like so:

```
bool first = true;

for (const auto &word: sentence) {
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        std::cout << " ";

    std::cout << word;
}
```

Don't abbreviate too much, just write `carthesian_product` instead of `cart_product`. The latter abbreviation is not common and might confuse others that do not know that you mean Carthesian product here.

## Use more algorithms?

Since you are already using some of the C++ standard library algorithms, why not use more? For example, instead of writing a `for`-loop to create the vector of vector of strings, write:

```
std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(),
               std::back_inserter(possibilities),
               [](std::string words){
                   return split(words, '|');
               });
```

Although arguably, it doesn't improve readability much here.

## Split off more functionality into their own functions

The `main()` function could be cleaned up and made more readable if you moved some of its parts to properly named functions. For example, instead of creating the vector of vector of strings inline, it would be nice it you could just write:

```
auto possibilities = split_possibilities(input);
```

Also, consider creating a `join()` function, so writing out all the permutations could be written as:

```
for (auto &sentence: sentences) {
    std::sort(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());

    do {
        std::cout << join(sentence, " ") << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of unnecessary string copying.

If you change all the `std::string`s to `std::string_view` and write your own `split` function (simple enough using `std::find`) it will be much faster.